# Armature - freely adapting bones in pose mode

Tags: armature, constraints, pose-mode

I wonder if there is a way to let a bone follow the pose of other bones.

Here is the rig i need this for:
[image]

The selected bones, representig the shoulders, mainly have the task of maintaining a realistic distance between the arms, but i would like them to translate and rotate according to the pose i configure for the arms.

Is there a way to do this? Like an "anti-constraint"?

Answer (score 1):

Found it,

i just extended the "Chain Length" of the IK constraint from the upper arms from one to two.

Animation noob, sorry for wasting peoples time!